# How to set txqueuelen on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, networking, ifconfig

How can I set the transmit queue length for a network interface on Mac OSX?  On linux the command would be

```
ifconfig en0 txqueuelen 5
```

but OSX doesn't recognize txqueuelen as a valid option.  Where does BSD manage this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to check the system defaults (send and receive queues):

```
sysctl net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen
sysctl net.link.generic.system.rcvq_maxlen
```

And to set the default transmit queue (current default 128) e.g.:

```
sysctl -w net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen=150
```

and default receive queue (current default 256) e.g.:

```
sysctl -w net.link.generic.system.rcvq_maxlen=260
```

It's unclear if it's possible to set a per interface queue length. The output queue length's default is set in the xnu kernel: bsd/net/if.h:#define IFQ_MAXLEN 128

On older kernels you used to be able to set the maximum input queue length on OSX as follows (e.g. to 100 packets) - which can be useful for tuning performance with incoming packets flows - it's the internal queue that packets are put when they come off the incoming interface:

```
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.intr_queue_maxlen=100
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, 'sysctl' is used for tuning TCP parameters.   I looked through the output of

```
 sysctl -a
```

and while I don't see anything that might be an exact match, there are a few possible parameters.  I must point out that BSD and Linux differ greatly in their internals, and there might not be an analogous txqueuelen adjustment.  (ie: the paradigm may not apply to MacOS's networking implementation)